# SSRS Date Culture Error

Tags: reporting-services, culture

I've got a strange error when trying to pass date parameters to SSRS.

All of the dates are retrieved using a DatePicker and validated so that only real dates are allowed.

However passing dates in the format dd/mm/yyyy causes SSRS to throw TypeMissmatchException if the day is 13 or higher.

I'm assuming this is due to the culture of SSRS being set to EN-US, is it possible to change this? or do I need to convert all dates that I send SSRS into American format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to send dates in military format yyyy-mm-dd if possible as that is always interpreted correctly regardless of culture settings.