# SSRS 2012 date culture settings

Tags: date, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

My issues is somewhat related to this article. [ssrs-date-culture-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502751/ssrs-date-culture-error)

I get the date type mismatch when generating a report using the SSRS 2012 web service in my website.

However this does not make sense as an older setup using SSRS 2005 works with all settings in line and the same.

Since we upgraded to SSRS 2012 this issue has popped up.

To explain the issue:
I have a website using shortdate format: en-ZA "dd/mm/YYYY"

The account that SSRS 2012 executes under: en-US "dd/mm/YYYY" (note it is different from the default en-US settings)

The website uses the web service "ReportExecution2005.asmx" and passes a dictionary of string to generate. In this dictionary the date is converted to string without a format.

I would assume that give the above setup, all culture settings are in line that this work but doesn't.

I tried converting the date to string using military format yyyy-mm-dd as stated in the other article and it works.

However it does not make sense why the internally hosted webservice within SSRS 2012 does not understand the format being passed to it.
Why doesn't it assume the region/culture setting as per settings in the registry for the account it is running under?

Could it be that it is looking at en-US and it ignoring the dd/mm/YYYY and using a default setting?

Another article mentioned using en-GB as it's default setting for short date is dd/mm/YYYY.
I tried changing the account to execute under en-GB but that does not work either. It's seem like it would only work with "yyyy-mm-dd"

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hi do you try use this in expression =Format(Fields!MyValue.Value,"dd/MM/yyyy"

Comment: Hi, that is the default date time culture settings. The only that did work is setting the account my app pool runs under to en-ZA "yyyy/MM/dd" which is the default setting for that region. The juice was not worth the squeeze so I just formatted the date ("yyyy/MM/dd") before passing to report server.